# postedbasefile always gives null value on mvc teleik grid ajax binding while uploading file

Tags: asp.net, forms, telerik

```
public ActionResult _InsertAjaxEditing(CountryMaster cntry, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
{
    uploading code
}
```

Comment: How is the file upload setup, could you post some markup?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you cannot upload files with Ajax requests. I suggest you move to server binding/editing.

By the way we are soon releasing a new Upload component which will help you achieve ajax uploading (well sort of). A beta is on its way.